# Why loop fails to count right colors in wrong place

Tags: c, loops, count

Iḿ trying to build a game where we are asked to enter guess code of colors to try and find the secret code. I manage to be abble to count correctly right colors in the right place (blacks) and right colors in the wrong place (whites).
What I cant figure out is how to count the right colors in the wrong place, while having 5 attempts, without repeating the count.
It is supposed to count no more than 5. I have the part of the code that doesnt seem to work, commented out.
If I do uncomment the code, the part that counts right colors in the wrong place, fails.
Any help will be appreciated.
p.s. I know the variables should be inside the functions :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define QTD  5   
#define MAX 10   
char secretCode[5][10] = {"yellow", "green", "red", "brown", "blue"}; //allowed colors 
char guessCode[5][10];
int black,white,counter=0;

void guess(char guessCode[5][10]){
    int count=0;
    char input[10];
    
    printf("Guess Code:\n");

    while(count<QTD){
        scanf("%s",input); 
        strcpy(guessCode[count], input);  
        count++;            
    }
    for (count = 0; count < QTD; count++)
    {
        printf("Guess Code:%s\n",guessCode[count]);
    }
}

int identical(char aux[10],char secretCode[5][10]){
    int j,i;
    for (j = 0; j < QTD; ++j)
    {
        if(strcmp(aux, secretCode[j]) == 0){                              
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(char secretCode[5][10],char guessCode[5][10], int *black, int *white,int *counter){
    int i, j,found=0;
    //contadores
    *black = *white = 0;
    char aux[10];
    char count[5][10];

    for(i=0; i<QTD; i++){   
        if(strcmp(guessCode[i], secretCode[i]) == 0){                                
            ++*black;
        }            
    } 

    for(i=0; i<QTD; i++){
        strcpy(aux,guessCode[i]);
        if(identical(aux,secretCode)==1){
            /*for(i=0; i<QTD; i++)
              {
              if(strcmp(aux, count[i]) == 0){
              printf("Color exists in count array");
              }else
              {
              strcpy(aux,count[i]);
              }
              }*/
            found++;
        }
        /*for (i = 0; i<QTD; i++)
          {
          if (count[i] != NULL)
          {
          counter++;
          }
            
          }*/
    }
    
    *white=found-*black;
    if (*white<0){
        *white=0;
    }
    printf("\n %d Count black!",*black); 
    printf("\n %d Count white!\n",*white);  

    printf("\n %d Count!",*counter);                
}

int main(){
    guess(guessCode);
    compare(secretCode,guessCode, &black, &white, &counter);
}
```

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with, don't comment it out.

Comment: This is called "bulls and cows". If you search SO for that name, you'll find lots of questions about it, and you'll find the algorithm.

Comment: We will need to mark pieces we already evaluated see:

| sec:  r, g, x, x ,x | gues:  g, g, x, x, x |
The second g was already found as `black`, we will found it again in pass two unless we mark that somehow. In `identical` we need to check that.